# What is process control block's file format?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, windows-kernel

I read about this in one of my textbooks, where it is mentioned quite briefly, but didn't quite understand what it meant and how it is defined. What is process control block file format? Is it XML? And is it similar to manifest.xml files in ros packages?

Answer (score 0):

The process control block is never stored as a file, and therefore doesn't have a file format.

Instead, it'd be a structure (e.g. `struct process_control_block { ...` in C) with various fields (process name, number of threads, amount of CPU time consumed, ...) that are set when the process is created, and then used and modified while the process is running, and then discarded/de-allocated when the process is terminated.

Note that Linux doesn't call it "PCB", it's called "Task Control Block" (because it's used for both processes and threads). You can find it relatively easily: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L723

Also; XML is so inefficient that anyone who uses it should probably be banned from touching a computer ever again. For a trivial example, a simple integer like 12345, which could be stored in 2 bytes with no need to waste CPU time parsing it; will become something like `<integer>1234</integer>` that takes 10 times as much space and 1000 times as many CPU cycles to parse. Advocates like to say it's "more human readable", but it's not (e.g. no way to tell if it's supposed to be kilowatts or micro-farads, or which range of numbers is acceptable, and it's unreadable for people who can't read English) - it's just an excuse not to have a decent tool (with internationalization, help, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The "Process Control Block" is an invention of some terrible books on operating systems to describe multiple data structures in a kernel. The initialism PCB in operating systems normally means Process Context Block, which is a data structure defined by a processor in which registers are stored in a context switch. XML does not appear in kernel data structures in any rationally designed operating system.